# debian/ubuntu - invert all colours in desktop session (colors)

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, colors

Sometimes I need to flip from a light colour scheme to a dark one quickly, and I need it to apply not just to the desktop theme but also to any webpages that are open etc.

On the Mac there's a neat shortcut for this (Cmd+Alt+Ctrl+8) - it simply inverts all colours displayed, so the screen looks like a photographic negative.

Is there an equivalent of this that I can use in my debian/ubuntu desktop sessions?

Comment: What Desktop Environment/Window manager do you use? Gnome? Unity? Cinnamon?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge - I'm using LXDE/Openbox, but I realise I was assuming the effect would happen lower down (in Xorg) - and there is an answer that does do this, hurrah.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A window manager independent way is:

```
xcalib -invert -alter
```

From the xcalib man page

> xcalib loads 'vcgt'-tag of ICC profiles to the X-server using the XVidMode Extension in order to calibrate your display.

You can install it using `sudo apt-get install xcalib`. To make it more convenient assign a keyboard shortcut to the command (e.g. Cmd+Alt+Ctrl+8).

Comment: It only inverts one of my two displays

Comment: @TristanT use `-s 0` for first screen and `-s 1` for second. [See also](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328622/19062).

Comment: gotta be carefulnif you are using `redshift` https://superuser.com/q/874859/202217

Comment: Using redshift over here. All you've got to do after the blink is fire a `redshift -o` Also, I think xcalib may have been updated? Or is better compatible with some drivers. Works fine on all 3 of my connected displays.

Comment: If you get "Error - unsupported ramp size 0", see https://askubuntu.com/questions/930084/xcalib-error-unsupported-ramp-size

Comment: `$ xcalib -invert -alter` 
`Error - unsupported ramp size 0` in fact produces this error for every option

Comment: I wonder now if it can be mixed with some other tool to invert only part (rectangular area) of the display.

Answer (score 4):

The following works on Pop-OS 21, which is an Ubuntu variant.

Settings > Accessibility > Zoom > Magnifier > Full Screen

[image]

Settings > Accessibility > Zoom > Color Effects > White on Black

[image]

Alt-Super-8

[image]

Comment: This leaves a weird square trail behind my cursor, but otherwise works well. If someone knows how to use `xcalib` (or any other approach) in a way that doesn't affect my `xrandr` brightness settings, I'd love to hear! Until this is good enough - thanks!

Comment: @joe I confirm the "weird square trail." Annoying but merely annoying in my opinion for ordinary work. Would be bad for a screencast.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Compiz, open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and enable *Negative*.  This will allow you to invert colors of a window (default shortcut is `Super+n`) or the whole desktop (default shortcut is `Super+m`).