# Inverse colors in all aplications running on Linux

Tags: linux, gui

Is it possible to change white background to black and black text to white but for all applications running on Linux including firefox, pidgin, text editor etc. ? It would be fine if it is possible via script so I could have night and day theme and switch them according my needs. I'm using openbox on Debian

Comment: Sorry, deleted answer because it wasn't precisely answering the question.

Comment: Does http://superuser.com/questions/570666/debian-ubuntu-invert-all-colours-in-desktop-session-colors help?